# Is this understanding of indexed collections correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am currently trying to study set theory. A professor at my school was kind enough to lend me a book (The Joy of Sets) and I just want to make sure I understand this correctly, before moving on.

The book defined indexed collections and intersections of set, and I think I understand the definition. Looking at the definition, I understand it to be something like this:

$X_1 \cup X_2 \cup X_3 \cup X_i$ where I is the set of numbers {1,2,3... i} and a similar concept for intersection.

But, I'm not sure if I'm understanding it when its applied to another case.

For example, theres an exercise in the book that says

"Prove that $\cup_{i \in I}(x_i  \cup y_i) = (\cup_{i \in I}x_i) \cup (\cup_{i \in I}y_i)$

If I were to write the first part out, would it be something along the lines of:

$(x_1 \cup y_1) \cup (x_2 \cup y_2) \cup (x_3 \cup y_3) \cup ...(x_i \cup y_i)$ ?

Or if the statement was, $\cup(z - x_i)$, is that equivalent to

$(z - x_1) \cup (z - x_2) \cup (z - x_3)... (z - x_i)$?

Is that correct or is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Indexed set does not have to be countable

Comment: The index set does not have to be countable, but whenever it is you have the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your concept only applies, if you have an finite union or interception. Because when you write $$X_1 \cup X_2 \cup \ldots \cup X_i$$ it means that you only have finitely many sets. Its better to think of $X_i$ as a function. You assign each $i\in I$ a set $X_i$. Note that $I$ does not need to be countable. So $$\cup_{i\in I} X_i$$ cannot always be represented as $$X_1 \cup X_2 \cup X_3 \cup \ldots \cup X_i \cup \ldots$$

*Example where $I$ is not countable:* Take $X_i = \{i\}$ for $i \in \mathbb R$ (here we have $I=\mathbb R$). You have $$\cup_{i\in I} X_i=\mathbb R$$ but you cannot represent $\cup_{i\in I} X_i$ as $$X_1 \cup X_2 \cup X_3 \cup \ldots \cup X_i \cup \ldots$$

Comment: What would be an example of where I isnt countable?

Comment: Take $I=\mathbb R$ for example

Comment: I am confused. If the point is to index the sets, how can the set I be something uncountable?

Comment: I have added an example in my answer...

Comment: I see now. Thank you!